# Django UnicodeDecodeError on alwaysdata.com server

Tags: python, django, unicode

I put my django project in the site alwaysdata.com and on HTML site everything looks great, but when I entered to ADMIN panel and try to open one of structure i got

```
 `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

In my project i have letter from Polish alphabet like 'ł','ą' etc. I figured out that probably i have to change coding from default ascii to utf-8. I changed it into my `modles.py` like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

and in `admin.py` the same way at begining of file.

I still have the same error. So there is my question, where should i change it and how? Maybe sth else causes the problem? Maybe there is other solution? Thanks.

Comment: is every "estrange" letter in comments? is there any other character like that in your data base? can you show that line?

Comment: My model where the problem is found looks like that : http://pastebin.com/jkigG8A7
There is no problem when i run project in my computer, only in alwaysdata.com. Element which contains error : miejsce = models.TextField(max_length=100)
Yes i have similiar data in my database in other models but there i use def __unicode__ to return them (then it works for this one) but i can't return element 'miejsca' like ID

Comment: mmmm ok, are you using 'variable.encode('utf8')' when you save/show data? it could fix it

Comment: no bro, use it when you save the object `obj = YourModel(miejsce = some_string.encode('utf-8'), ....)`

Comment: In my models.py it looks like :
 miejsce = models.TextField(max_length=100)

In HTML it works but in ADMIN panel, when I try to look at my databse (in Mecz) the error is showing up.

When i tried to change that to  miejsce=models.TextField(max_length=100).encode('utf-8') i got error:'TextField' object has no attribute 'encode'. I know TextField has no attribute like this but no idea where i have to add this .encode to?

Comment: by the way, I hate to say it but i CAN'T open pastebin. It was blocked in Venezuela :'(

Comment: no man, `models.TextField(max_length=100).encode('utf-8')` is wrong, I'll try to explain in an answer although I don't know if it is your problem

Comment: I dont save it anywhere like You wrote, it's done automaticly added to database and i don't create any object

Comment: so, where/how do you automaticly added them?

Comment: What i put on pastebin before : 
class Mecz(models.Model):      
    kolejka = models.IntegerField('Kolejka')
    data = models.DateField()
    miejsce = models.TextField(max_length=100)
       
    gospodarz = models.ForeignKey(Zespol,related_name="as_host")
    gosc = models.ForeignKey(Zespol,related_name="as_guest")
   
    bramki_gospodarz = models.IntegerField('Bramki Gospodarzy')
    bramki_gosc = models.IntegerField('Bramki Gosci',)
    description = models.TextField('Uwagi')
   
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "[%d]: %s <=> %s "%(self.kolejka,self.gospodarz,self.gosc)

Comment: In django in my admin panel when i add an position (one 'Mecz') by 'green plus' sign its shown in some way automaticly later. I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

models.py

```
class Mecz(models.Model): 
    kolejka = models.IntegerField('Kolejka') 
    data = models.DateField() 
    miejsce = models.TextField(max_length=100) 
    gospodarz = models.ForeignKey(Zespol,related_name="as_host") 
    gosc = models.ForeignKey(Zespol,related_name="as_guest") 
    bramki_gospodarz = models.IntegerField('Bramki Gospodarzy') 
    bramki_gosc = models.IntegerField('Bramki Gosci',) 
    description = models.TextField('Uwagi') 

def save(self, *args, **kw):

    miejsce = miejsce.encode('utf-8')

    super(Mecz, self).save(*args, **kw)
```

I guess you save data from admin and not by yourself, so you can override save model method to do whatever you want before save.

Here the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

I'm not sure if it is your problem but I  can't explain it in a comment

Hope t helps

Comment: I wrote this into my model Mecz but it didn't help :(
   
def save(self, *args, **kw):
        self.miejsce = self.miejsce.encode('utf-8')
        super(Mecz, self).save(*args, **kw)